# Chrome Extension causes Chrome to become unusably slow

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been developing a Chrome extension, however I have done most of my testing on Firefox, and there it works just fine. On Chrome, it seems to make the whole browser slow down to a crawl, and I am unaware of how to diagnose the problem. Could anyone suggest any methods where I can debug this?

Comment: In short: use devtools. For a full story see tutorials on using devtools to debug performance issues.

Comment: As an update: I've found that this is specifically related to the number of match urls I put inside the content scripts portion of the manifest.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was particularly tricky, profiling my JS didn't yield any results because the issue was in Chrome itself. I noticed this issue a long time ago when I was loading unpacked plugins into my Chrome, however I chalked it up to the dev tools just being bad (a big mistake on my behalf, it happens the same on the chrome web store with developer mode turned off).

The way I solved this was to simply set "<all_urls>" in the matches section, then perform the matching myself in the background script, if the match was true I would "require" my original content script.